# preg_replace not ignoring [] from string

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is my code :

```
$string = "Hello this is my text [readmore] and this is remaining text";
echo preg_replace("[readmore]","",$string);
```

This is my **expected** output :

```
Hello this is my text and this is remaining text
```

This is my **actual** output :

```
Hello this is my text [] and this is remaining text
```

Question is simple how to get ride of "[]" too ?

Comment: use `str_replace` function, check my answer. it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `[` & `]`. Try below regexp,

```
preg_replace("/\[([^\[\]]++|(?R))*+\]/", "", $string);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Hello this is my text and this is remaining text
```

[**CodePad Demo.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VsDLVz)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets for use in regular expressions. Also, you might want to look at the manual for [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), since you left off the `/` that needs to be around your regex.

```
$string = "Hello this is my text [readmore] and this is remaining text";
echo preg_replace("/\[readmore\]/","",$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the '[' and ']' characters:

This script:

```
 $string = "Hello this is my text [readmore] and this is remaining text";
 echo preg_replace("[\\[readmore\\] ]","",$string);
```

This result (I tested this):

```
 Hello this is my text and this is remaining text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace`

```
$string = "Hello this is my text [readmore] and this is remaining text";
echo str_replace("[readmore]","",$string);
```

**Output**

```
Hello this is my text and this is remaining text
```